# How can i redirect HTTP to HTTPS in laragon

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, telegram, laragon

I want to use windows `Laragon` for `Telegram` bot with `webhook`.
I use [`let's encrypt`](https://sslforfree.com) for active `SSL certificate`. 
I used manual verification create `.well-known` file downloaded zip certificate and replaced it to

```
/etc/appache2/sll.
```

now when I want to using https://developerpiel.com (my domain) browser show me `ssl is actived by letsencrypt`. I used

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot(token)/setWebhookurl=https://developerpie.com/robot/bot.php
```

and its return me

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": true,
  "description": "Webhook is already set"
}
```

but when I want to use `Telegram` api methods I can't receive any data from `Telegram` webhook.
I think it will fix if requests redirects automatically to `HTTPS`instead of `HTTP`

How can config it whit `Laragon` on windows?

I found half of answer EDIT:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName www.developerpie.com 
Redirect permanent / https://www.developerpie.com/ 
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    <Directory "C:/laragon/www/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      C:/laragon/etc/ssl/laragon.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   C:/laragon/etc/ssl/laragon.key
</VirtualHost>
```

I used this config now when I load my web site auto browser automatically redirect to `https` but Telegram web hook still doesn't work

Comment: If your SSL is valid so don't worry about SSL . it's green and it should work fine. click `/start` on your bot and log webhook via `file_put_contents()` and give me the result. You also can contact me on Telegram @GameO7er

Comment: how can i use file_put_contents() method

Comment: {"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://developerpie.com/robot/bot.php","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":21,"last_error_date":1566230202,"last_error_message":"SSL error {error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}","max_connections":40}}

Comment: i have ssl error but my website cetificated by letsencrypt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your result from `Telegram` server :

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": {
    "url": "https://developerpie.com/robot/bot.php",
    "has_custom_certificate": false,
    "pending_update_count": 21,
    "last_error_date": 1566230202,
    "last_error_message": "SSLrror {error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}",
    "max_connections": 40
  }
}
```

and this picture is the result of your SSL test by [SSLShoppre.com](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://developerpie.com/)
[image: SSL Shopper test result]
so follow this [link](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/windows-cross-signed-chain.htm).